# Как прогнать только интеграционные тесты на удаленной машине в командной строке?

Tags: spring-boot

Spring-boot приложение, запускаемое на удаленном сервере командой

```
java -jar target\myApp.jar --spring.profiles.active=dev
```

То есть разные профили под разные сервера.

Какой командой прогнать интеграционные тесты поверх этого приложения? 
Нужны ли для каждого сервера - свой профиль еще и в тестах?
Нужно ли как-то особым образом помечать ИТ в коде?

Comment: Зависит от того чем Вы пользуетесь, JUnit, TestNG?

Comment: @МихаилРебров ИТ  на JUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В `JUnit` >= 4.8 есть категории.

Аннотацию `@Category` можно проставить как над классом, так и над методом.
В аннотации `@Category` можно указать как одну категорию, так и массив.

Примеры:

```
@Category(Category1.class)
public class SomeTest {

    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        ....
    }
}
```

или

```
public class SomeTest {

    @Test
    @Category(Category2.class)
    public void testMethod1() {
        ...
    }

    @Test
    @Category({Category1.class, Category3.class})
    public void testMethod2() {
        ....
    }
}
```

В качестве категории можно указать класс или интерфейс.
Т.к. нам нужно исключительно промаркировать группы, используются чаще последние.

Запустить всё это можно с помощью `Suite` и с помощью `Maven`.

**Запуск с помощью Suite**

С использованием `Suite` в нашем вооружении имеются аннотации `@IncludeCategory` для включения категории и `@ExcludeCategory` для исключения.

Примеры:

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@IncludeCategory(Unit.class)
@SuiteClasses( { Test1.class, Test2.class })
public class UnitTestSuite {}
```

и

```
@RunWith(Categories.class)
@ExcludeCategory(Unit.class)
@SuiteClasses( { Test1.class, Test2.class })
public class IntegrationTestSuite {}
```

Важно понимать:

- аннотации `@ExcludeCategory` и `@IncludeCategory` можно использовать
  одновременно
- над одним классом можно указать только одну аннотацию `@ExcludeCategory` и 
  только одну аннотацию `@IncludeCategory`
- одна аннотация `@ExcludeCategory` или `@IncludeCategory` может содержать только одну категорию

Всё это немного осложняет процесс. Выход из всего этого - наследование категорий. Здесь также стоит отметить плюс испоьлзования интерфейсов - это множественное наследование.

```
public interface Category1 extends Category12,Category13 {}
```

**Запуск с помощью Maven**

Maven является более гибким и используемым вариантом.

Для запуска нам понадобится `maven-surefire-plugin`

Пример конфигурации:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <groups>com.example.cat.Category1</groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

> Внутренняя зависимость в плагине surefire-junit47 обязательно должна
>   присутствовать, иначе Maven будет игнорировать аннотации @Category.

- Для исключения категорий используется тег `excludedGroups`
- Для включения категорий испоьлзуется тег `groups`
- Тег `groups` позволяет включать в себя несколько категорий

Примеры:

```
<configuration>
    <excludedGroups>com.example.cat.Category2</excludedGroups>
</configuration>
```

и

```
<configuration>
    <groups>com.example.cat.Category1,com.example.cat.Category2</groups>
</configuration>
```

Источники:

- http://internetka.in.ua/group-junit-category/
- https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/

Comment: Если выбрать вариант с аннотацией и мавен плагином - как запускать только ит? mvn test?

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov, `mvn test`  во втором случае, в первом запускаете также `java -jar target\myApp.jar  packageName.SuiteName` только с указанием класса сьюта

Comment: @VladislavOsipenkov однако, вариант с Maven мне кажется более удобным